# mysql - how to not repeat subquery of derived table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, derived

I want to know how many times the value of a column shows up in the results and include it in a column of the result for each row. How can I achieve this without repeating the subquery for the derived table twice? If I replace (derivedtable) by "t" in the COUNT subquery, it says the table doesn't exist.

```
SELECT
col1,
col2,
col3,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (derivedtable) WHERE t.col1=col1)
FROM (derivedtable) AS t
```

Comment: Short of creating a real view: not possible using MySQL because it lacks common table expressions.

Comment: By "without repeating the subquery" do you mean the fact that you have to type it twice, or is MySQL executing it for each line of the results?

Comment: I meant that MySQL will execute it twice (more than that actually once for each rows of the SELECT), I assume that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `group by`?

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, COUNT(*)
FROM (derivedtable) AS t
GROUP BY col1;
```

This will return an arbitrary value of `col2` and `col3`.  You can get a complete list using `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT col1, group_concat(col2) as col2s, group_concat(col3) as col3s, COUNT(*)
FROM (derivedtable) AS t
GROUP BY col1;
```

EDIT:

If you really want to do this without repeated the derived table, you can use variables:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,
       @col1cnta := if(@col1a = col1, @col1cnta, col1cnt) as col1cnt,
       @col1a := col
FROM (SELECT col1, col2, col3,
             @col1cnt := if(@col1 = col1, 0, @col1cnt) + COUNT(*) as col1cnt,
             @col1 := col1
      FROM (derivedtable) t cross join
           (select @col1 := '', @col1cnt := 0) const
      GROUP BY col1
     ) t cross join
     (select @col1a := '', @col1cnta := 0) const
ORDER BY col1, col1cnt desc;
```

The idea here is to do the subcount for each combination of the three columns.  Then, sort the results by `col1` but with the counts in reverse order and copy the largest value through all rows for a given `col1`.

Comment: I do need a complete listing that's why I didn't use GROUP BY. However I wasn't aware of the group_concat function after reading about it, it won't be possible for me to use it because I can't do any post processing of the results to break down the results into seperate rows because I'm feeding the mysql results directly into a php class that won't allow this. I wouldn't say impossible but it would be very complicated, I need another solution if there's one.

Comment: @navark . . . Why do you need a count by `col1` if you are also returning values from other columns?  Wouldn't you want a count specific to each row?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but it is specific to each row in the sense that I need each row to evaluate the value of its own col1 "WHERE t.col1=col1". I need this done entirely in mysql if it's at all possible because doing it in php would be very complicated.

Comment: But for more clarification, I need to sort the results by "how many times col1 shows up in the results", ex : if row 1 has col1 = 3 and col1 = 3 shows up 20 times in total, it will rank higher than if it showed up only 10 times, the idea is to use that column I'm trying to create into the order by clause

Comment: Your solution still has the problem of using GROUP BY and so not a complete listing. However I have adapted it a bit and managed to do what I wanted. Thanks very much. I will post the solution as soon as I can (can't because not enough reputation with the site).

Answer (score 0):

```
Solution :

SELECT col1, col2, col3,
       @col1cnta := if(@col1a = col1, @col1cnta, col1cnt) as col1cntfinal,
       @col1a := col1
FROM (SELECT col1, col2, col3,
             @col1cnt := if(@col1 = col1, @col1cnt+1, 1) as col1cnt,
             @col1 := col1
      FROM (derivedtable) t cross join
           (select @col1 := '', @col1cnt := 0) const
      ORDER BY col1
     ) t2 cross join
          (select @col1a := '', @col1cnta := 0) const
ORDER BY col1, col1cnt desc;
```